# connect Wifly(RN-171) module's SPI to Arduino's SPI pins?

Tags: arduino, wifi, xbee

I've searched a lot about the Wifly(RN-171 Wifi Bee) module on how to connect the SPI pins to Arduino's SPI but it seems that the SPI pins are not even connected to the module's Pins!

These are the links for the module's datasheets:

http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/TEL0067/rn-171-ds-v3.21.pdf

http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/TEL0067/rn-171-xv-ds-v1.04r.pdf

I was thinking if there's a way to configure some GPIO pins to connect to the spi pins, but also I couldn't find anything about it.

I need some help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, RN-171 does not support SPI. It's reserved for factory flashing and testing only - and even then they told me in a support ticket that RN-171 cannot be flashed with RN-ISP after all over SPI.

However, RN-171 does support UART which can be used with Arduino.